# Create default values for dictionary in python

Tags: python, coding-style, performance

Let's have a method that would cache results it calculates.

**"If" approach**:

```
def calculate1(input_values):
    if input_values not in calculate1.cache.keys():
        # do some calculation
        result = input_values
        calculate1.cache[input_values] = result
    return calculate1.cache[input_values]
calculate1.cache = {}
```

**"Except" approach**:

```
def calculate2(input_values):
    try:
       return calculate2.cache[input_values]
    except AttributeError:
       calculate2.cache = {}
    except KeyError:
       pass
    # do some calculation
    result = input_values
    calculate2.cache[input_values] = result
    return result
```

**"get/has" approach**:

```
def calculate3(input_values):

    if not hasattr(calculate3, cache):
        calculate3.cache = {}

    result = calculate3.cache.get(input_values)
    if not result:
        # do some calculation
        result = input_values
        calculate3.cache[input_values] = result
    return result
```

**Is there another (faster) way? Which one is most *pythonic*? Which one would you use?**

*Note*: There's a speed difference:

```
calculate = calculateX # depening on test run
for i in xrange(10000):
    calculate(datetime.utcnow())
```

Results `time python test.py`:

```
calculate1: 0m9.579s
calculate2: 0m0.130s
calculate3: 0m0.095s
```

Comment: your benchmarking looks fishy to me - I don't believe the third method is 100 times faster. Did you by any chance reuse the cache from the first run?

Comment: Not sure, but the huge disparity between the first run and subsequent runs may be due to the interpreter compiling the script (probably better to time within Python then the time it takes your OS to load, launch, etc.).

Comment: Nope. Have a look http://files.myopera.com/ezimir/files/test.py Getting `.keys()` is that slow...

Comment: Using keys can indeed slow, at least in python 2 (where it generates a list). It also means linear search. WhyTF not just use `input_values not in calculate1.cache`? That's a simple hash lookup and propably close to the others (as in, < 0.300s).

Comment: @delnan: Wow, it's actually faster!

Comment: If you want to measure the execution time of Python code you can use the `timeit` module which will probably give you more accurate answers than `time`.

Comment: Your benchmark seems inappropriate; at least on my system aren't using values from the cache, as each loop takes more than a microsecond.  Add print len(calculate.cache) and try having something that checks the cache occasionally.  Maybe datetime.utcnow().microsecond % 500

Comment: @jimbob Thank you! `key in calculate.cache` approach is consistently faster than the others even with actual #calculation and cache reading in place.

Comment: @MartinToth collections.defaultdict is the best pythonic (and likely fastest) solution to the question implied in the title.  That is you have a dict that will only have some keys get set, but you want the unfilled keys that are later requested to then get set with some static default value (such as 0, [], {}, or "").  What you seem to be doing is memoization rather than setting default values to uncalled expressions.  E.g., you check whether the value was previously set in the cache or not and then fill it.

Comment: @jimbob Memoization, of course... Should I restate/rework the question, because now it may cause some confusion? (by rework I mean post some "calculate" examples where 1 memoization style is used, and only "defaultdict" style changes?

Comment: Eh; I just don't think a defaultdict particularly will help if what you are just trying to do is memoize.  And memoization is probably best done in python with a decorator class. See ans below.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). It's designed precisely for this purpose.

Comment: defaultdict seems logical, but I wonder if it is *faster* than other methods ? Sometimes I had bad surprises with such python extensions.

Comment: Who cares if it's slower (even if it is)? It's the right solution. If it becomes a bottlenect, replace it with a hand-tuned implementation. And if it made it into the stdlib, at least it's complexity is propably fine.

Comment: @kriss `0m0.101s` with the `defaultdict`

Comment: @delnan: the OP asked for performance, clearly he cares. Beside that I disagree with the pythonic mindset `there is (only) **One** right solution`, that is subjective, and I like to know if what I use is concise, simple, fast, several of them at once... and make informed choices. But in this case defaultdict clearly has concision, efficiency and simplicity for it.

Comment: At any rate, that was exactly the answer I was looking for to my (admittedly different from the OP's) question -- I don't care about performance right now, just readability/maintainability. Thanks, unutbu! :)

Answer (score 5):

Of course; this is Python after all: Just use a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 3):

Well if you are trying to memoize something, its best to use a Memoize class and decorators.

```
class Memoize(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if args not in self.cache:
            self.cache[args] = self.func(*args)
        return self.cache[args]
```

Now define some function to be memoized, say a key-strengthening function that does say 100,000 md5sums of a string hashes:

```
import md5

def one_md5(init_str):
    return md5.md5(init_str).hexdigest()

@Memoize
def repeat_md5(cur_str, num=1000000, salt='aeb4f89a2'):
    for i in xrange(num):
        cur_str = one_md5(cur_str+salt)
    return cur_str
```

The `@Memoize` function decorator is equivalent to defining the function and then defining `repeat_md5 = Memoize(repeat_md5)`.  The first time you call it for a particular set of arguments, the function takes about a second to compute; and the next time you call its near instantaneous as it read from its cache.

As for the method of memoization; as long as you aren't doing something silly (like the first method where you do `if key in some_dict.keys()` rather than `if key in some_dict`) there shouldn't be much a significant difference.  (The first method is bad as you generate an array from the dictionary first, and then check to see if the key is in it; rather than just check to see whether the key is in the dict (See [Coding like a pythonista](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#use-in-where-possible-1))).  Also catching exceptions will be slower than if statements by nature (you have to create an exception then the exception-handler has to handle it; and then you catch it).